# Two way SSL - X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile - WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: c#, tls1.2, x509certificate2, winhttp

I am trying to call an API which requires two way SSL (TLS 1.2) and I have the following code:

```
var myCert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(_publicFilename, _privateFilename);

using (var handler = new WinHttpHandler())
{
    handler.ClientCertificateOption = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (x, y, z, w) => true;
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var postData = new StringContent("", UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("<API Endpoint>", postData);

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

However, when I call that I get the following WinHttp exception:

> Error 12185 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'No
> credentials were available in the client certificate.'.

Also in the windows event viewer I get the following error message:

> The TLS client credential's certificate does not have a private key
> information property attached to it. This most often occurs when a
> certificate is backed up incorrectly and then later restored. This
> message can also indicate a certificate enrollment failure.

Unable to figure out what the issue is. I am using the exact same certificate and key in postman and it works fine.

Comment: Open pem file with Notepad and see what is in the file.

Comment: It has "begin private key" then a long base64 string and then "end private key".

Comment: What are you doing with Postman that is working?  TLS is performed before the HTTPS request is sent.  The client automatically sends a TLS to server and server responds with a certificate block with a list of names of certificates names.  The client then looks up the names of the certificate in the stores to find a certificate with the matching name.  When the TLS completes then the HTTP Request is sent.  The certificate has to be put into the stores. before the request is sent.

Comment: @jdweng Please check this url : https://i.stack.imgur.com/599Y8.png

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  We do not know that Postman is using the same TLS key that you c# code is using.  I read what Bartonjs said.  You may need an admin to install a new key.  The error message says that the name of the key(s) sent from the server to client did not match a key in the user stores.  Postman is working but we do not know if Postman used the same key that is in the certificate you loaded.  Do your code work without using the new certificate (using a key already loaded).  Not sure but did read in past that the certificate need to be in both machine and user stores.

Comment: For TLS to work the certificate has to be installed in both the client and server.  What may be happening is your new certificate is not in the server.  Your code is telling the client to use only the certificate in your code and ignore the other certificates in the certificate block sent from the server.  Postman work since it is using a certificate from the certificate block from server and your c# isn't working because you are using a different certificate that is not in the certificate block.

Comment: @jdweng The Url with the screenshot is what I did with postman. The client certificate and key are fine. They are installed on the server also. Thats why on postman I was getting valid results for my API calls. But in C# code I get an SSL handshake error. I have verified my certificate by encrypting with the public key and decrypting with the private key.

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  If you are using Net 4.7.2 or later Net defaults to using the operating system for TLS.  You would need to change the config setting to use Net for TLS.  So your certificate isn't being used if TLS is being done with the operating system.

Comment: I am on .Net 5.0. Can you please tell me which config setting needs to be changed? OS = Windows 10 Home (19042.985)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true#switchsystemnetdontenablesystemdefaulttlsversions

Comment: @jdweng I tried the following code at program launch:
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.ServiceModel.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions", true);

It still give me the same error. I guess all it does is let the app decide which TLS version to use instead of the OS negotiating it.

Comment: @jdweng Could this be something related to this github post? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45680#issuecomment-740069757

Comment: I do not know all the fine details of all the different combinations of things that could be happening.  I suspect you are now defaulting to TLS 1.3.  I think we need to use a sniffer to determine the TLS version be used.  It should be in your code that selected TLS 1.2.  But the link says that you are now enabling the highest value of TLS available.  There may be a bug that your selection of TLS to 1.2 may not be working.  Then we may have to go into the registry to force TLS 1.2.  Or try setting in your Browser Setting only TLS 1.2.  Net uses same settings as browser.

Comment: I checked via wireshark. My client app negitates Tls1.2 only. However in the handshake process after "Server Hello Done" and client certificate request causes my client app to send a RST. And I get the following Error:

"A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013"

Comment: I also tried putting the certificate in the windows keystore and getting it from there in my app. But it still fails. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Error 10013 just indicates that the encryption at client and server did not match.    Compare Postman results with c#  Maybe switch to fiddler instead of wireshark.    Fiddler tries every certificate in stores to determine which certificate was actually used to encrypt the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS on Windows (WinHttpHandler, SslStream, or the default HTTP handler (which uses SslStream)) requires that the certificate have a named private key.

You can do that on a temporary basis by importing a PFX without PersistKeySet... but how do you get a PFX?  Well, pretty easy.

```
var myCert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(_publicFilename, _privateFilename);

using (var tmpCert = new X509Certificate2(myCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx)))
using (var handler = new WinHttpHandler())
{
    ...
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(tmpCert);
    ...
}
```

The named key will be deleted when tmpCert gets Disposed.  If you have complex or long life, you can create the cert not in a using statement.  If the cert gets garbage collected and the process stays active long enough to run the finalizers the key will get cleaned up then.

Comment: Hi @bartonjs. I am still learning SSL, cryptography etc. My knowledge in that field is limited. Can you please explain what a "named private key" is? Also I tried the above code. Its still not working. I get the following error : "Error 12185 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'No credentials were available in the client certificate.'."

Comment: I have also been following around with your posts in this github thread : "https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749". But still a bit stuck.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true#switchsystemnetdontenablesystemdefaulttlsversions

Comment: I have this error now: Error 12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A security error occurred'. Just completely lost with this one

Comment: Hi @bartonjs. Please help. Head over heels with this issue for almost a week now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and ended up having to convert the cert type (using iHttpClientFactor).  `soPemString` and `soKeyString` are the text from pem and key files, as strings. `soCertificate` by itself gave me OP's error, but the converted `soCertificatePkcs` worked perfectly.

In Startup.cs of a Web API app:

```
// using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

// Http Client (for IHttpClientFactory) - StackOverflow
var soCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(soPemString.AsSpan(), soKeyString.AsSpan());
var soCertificatePkcs = new X509Certificate2(soCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
var soHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
soHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(soCertificatePkcs);
services.AddHttpClient("StackOverflow", client =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("StackOverflow");
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
    client.DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20;
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => soHandler);
```